# How to install the bootloader of Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, 22.04, windows-10, bootloader

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my HDD and Windows 10 on my SSD. A few days ago, I encountered an issue with Windows - it froze during startup. Despite attempts to use chkdsk and repair system files, nothing worked. Frustrated, I decided to reset Windows with the "keep my files" option, however the process failed and to my dismay deleted all my files.

Subsequently, when I tried to reinstall Windows, I encountered another problem - there was an issue with the SSD. Investigating further I discovered that the Ubuntu bootloader had been removed, rendering me unable to access Ubuntu.

Update on the situation: I changed my SSD and installed Windows, but now when I look at my partitions in the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 "tried installing Ubuntu again" the `/root` is safe, `/home` is unknown or corrupted and `/swap` is unknown. I didn't complete the installation because I was scared to lose my /home partition data. I don't know what to do, I have tried using Boot-Repair tool for Ubuntu, but it gives me an error every time. How can I save or at least be able to backup the data on my `/home` partition?

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu's default install of UEFI boot files is into the first drive's ESP - efi system partition. That often is the Windows drive. I prefer an ESP on Ubuntu drive with its own boot files, but often let the installer install to first drive. You can use Boot-Repair or chroot into your install and totally reinstall grub to new ESP on Windows drive. Or create an ESP on Ubuntu drive. You first need to update fstab with new UUID of new ESP. Use advanced mode for total reinstall of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Update on the situation: i changed my ssd and installed windows but now when i look at my partitions in the installation of ubuntu 22.04"tried installing ubuntu again" the /root is safe, /home is unknown or corrupted and /swap is unknown. I didn't complete the installation because i was scared to lose my /home partition data. I don't know what to do, i have tried using boot repair tool for ubuntu but it gives me an error everytime. How can i save or atleast be able to backup the data on /home partition?

Comment: You do have good backup of /home? That plus a few more things are required before any major system change. Applies to Windows also. Swap as unknown is normal as it is unformatted, but usually is known as swap as seen at top. Was install encrypted? Was partition ext4 or some other Linux format. Does testdisk show files with deeper search. If it does immediately backup to another drive, some have found files, but then never found them again. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Not sure I have seen unusable on drive. Is drive damaged?